# Display youtube api v3 title and thumbnail use Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, youtube

I got youtube API. Now I want to display my channel video in my website.
I tried this but it not work.
My angular code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet,contentDetails&channelId=UC1GU2NAvytA-eWWKUNkA11w&key=MYKEY")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.videos = response.data;

        });

});
```

My html code

```
 <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat="x in videos">
                    <td>{{ x.title }}</td>

                  </tr>
                </tbody>
       </table>
```

Please tell me a way to get the job done!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you getting any error? can you share `videos` json?

Comment: Your code will work if your response contains the key `data` which then contain the key `title`. Hitting the URL you have mentioned in your code, i get an error. Try to enter a valid url to get your code working

Comment: Also try `$scope.videos = response.data.data;`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it
Change Angular

```
 $scope.videos = response.data;//before
 $scope.videos = response.data.items;//now
```

In the HTML

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in videos">
         <td>{{ x.snippet.title }}</td>

   </tr>
```

Take a lot of research to make it. Nothing many good tutorial about this out there. Most of them use jquery.